# How to target all CSS link selectors?

Tags: css

Is there a better way to target these selectors instead of having to repeat them like below?

```
h1 a:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 a:active {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 a:link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, simply separate them with commas:

```
h1 a:hover, h1 a:active, h1 a:link, h1 a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

You might want to brush up on [the basics of CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We can use commas for a separate style CSS and reduce CSS lines.

```
h1 a:hover,
h1 a:active,
h1 a:link,
h1 a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: How is your answer any different than mine? Also, what are "commons"?

Comment: I was edited its comms. please ref. CSS coding standard : https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/css/